# Prove that the following set is dense in real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to prove the following statement.

Let {$a_{n}$} be a sequence of positive real numbers converging to $0$.
Prove that the set $E$ = {$ka_{n}$: $k$$\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$, $n$$\in$ $\mathbb{N}$} is dense in R.

I know that $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\lfloor x /a_{n}\rfloor$$a_{n}$$=x$ for all $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. Is it possible that I can prove the statement above using this theorem that I know?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What has to do at all that limit you mention with $\;E\;$ ?? I can't see the floor function in the definition of $\;E\;$ or anything...

Comment: The formula you mentioned shows that every real number is the limit of a sequence of elements of $E$. This proves that $E$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track, all you need to add is the observation that $\lfloor x/a_n \rfloor$ is an integer, let's call it $k_n$.

We know that $d(k_n a_n,x) \le |a_n| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ because 
$$k_n a_n \le x < (k_n+1) a_n
$$
(I suspect this part you know already, from what you wrote).

It follows that $k_na_n$ is a sequence of elements of $E$ that converges to $x$, because
$$0 \le x - k_n a_n \le a_n
$$
and so, by the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem),
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(x - k_n a_n) = 0
$$
$$x - \lim_{n\to\infty} k_na_n = 0
$$
$$x = \lim_{n\to\infty} k_na_n
$$
Since we have shown that an arbitrary real number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ can be written as a limit of some sequence of points in $E$, it follows that $E$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In fact, what I would like to prove is that there exists an element $x$ of $E$ such that $a<x<b$ where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary real numbers (i.e. $a<ka_{n}<b$ where $k$ is an integer). I think what you have commented for me is that the sequence in the last sentence converges to $x$. Could you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you didn't understand, but I added some details.

Comment: thank you so much for your clarification. Your explanation surely has helped me a lot! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You could also look at it from a topologist point of view. You need to show that $E$ intersects every non-empty open interval, i.e. a set of the form $(b,c)$ with $b<c$. But what can you say about ${\Bbb Z} a_n$ when $|a_n|< c-b$?